# Ksoap2 webservice does not return JSON if it is in large size in Android 4.4.2 but returns complete JSON in Android 2.2

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am integrating ksoap2 webservice in my android app that scans a barcode, sends it as parameter to webservice method and gets a json in response. Now the issue is that if the json is larger in size then I recieve a null, but if the json is smaller in size, i recieve it. I am creating this app on Android kitkat(4.4.2) and using ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar. If I change the build path of my project to Android 2.2 then the whole json is recieved but I want my app on Android 4.4.2, please help me resolve this issue.

Here is my code for webservice

```
public class SoapWebservice {
private static final String NAMESPACE   = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/";
 private static final String URL = "http://*****my webservice***.org/webservice.php?wsdl";
 private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "AddServicePortType";

 private static String return_string = "No response";

    /**
     * This method return Producer List from barcode & details in JSON string format.
     * Scanner class invoke this method
     * */

    public static String returnProducersFromBarCode(DotNetWebService activity, int id,String barcode,String device,String language){
        Log.i("Function Name","returnProducersFromBarCode");
        Log.i("Parameters","Member ID:"+id+",Barcode:"+barcode+",Device:"+device+",Language:"+language);

        String METHOD_NAME = "returnProducersFromBarCode";
        SoapObject soapRequest = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"returnProducersFromBarCode");


        soapRequest.addProperty("a", id);  
        soapRequest.addProperty("b", barcode);  
        soapRequest.addProperty("c", device);  
        soapRequest.addProperty("d", language);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soap_envelope  = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER10); 
        soap_envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapRequest);
        soap_envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;

        //HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 2000000000);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug  = true;
        SoapPrimitive   soapResponse  = null;
        try {
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            soap_envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION,soap_envelope);
            Log.i("SoapWebServier-soap_envelope:",""+soap_envelope.getResponse());

            soapResponse =  (SoapPrimitive) soap_envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("SoapWebServier-soap_response:",""+soapResponse.toString());


            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }catch (IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        if(soapResponse != null){
            return_string =  soapResponse.toString();
            }
        return return_string;
    }
 }
```

I am calling its method in my activity in async task

```
private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            String json = calculate();
          Intent i = new Intent(DotNetWebService.this, JsonActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("json", json);
          startActivity(i);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }

  public String calculate(){



      int id = 106;
      String barcode = "2345678901234";
      String device = "Mobile";
      String language = "en";
      //Call Webservice class method and pass values and get response
      String aResponse = SoapWebservice.returnProducersFromBarCode(DotNetWebService.this , id, barcode, device, language);   


      Log.i("AndroidExampleOutput", "----"+aResponse);

      return aResponse;


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue but my JSON string is returned on 4.4.2 but not in 4.2.2

The problem relates to HttpTransportSE.call(SOAP_ACTION,soap_envelope); method. This method attempts to load a StringBuilder with string retuned. An out of memory exception is thrown if this string is too large.

I also welcome more info

### Edited

set your manifest file to
android:largeHeap="true"

and it will work